# Amazon S3 Static Web Hosting with ASPX file extension but pure HTML

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to host web pages with .aspx extension but without dynamic code, including only HTML?

For example, index.aspx as

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">
</head>
<body>
This is a fake ASPX page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you try? You could try creating a bucket and uploading the file?

Comment: I enabled static web hosting, redirected my domain. I can serve .html and files without an extension but .aspx files fails. I edited content-type metadata as text/html but no help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

[Example](https://aspx-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/fake.aspx)

When you upload your file add the following metatag

`Content-Type: text/html`

In this case, the object is **public**

Comment: I did the same, maybe caching prevents me to see correct response, I am checking once more

Comment: did you add the content-type meta in object properties?

Comment: I think it was cache that put me into a dissapointment, but it works :) thanks

Comment: Yes I did, in Properties > Metatag > I removed existing Content-type entry and added once more as html/text